# PHP namespaces - Instantiate new object or call function directly?

Tags: php

I'm pretty new to PHP and i'm trying to learn namespacing to a reasonable level.

I have found that I can use a function from another class by doing the following:

```php
use Sonic\queries\projects;

$test = new projects();

$project = $test->getSingleProject($projectid);
```

However I can also access the function by simply doing the following:

```php
$project = Sonic\queries\projects::getSingleProject($projectid);
```

Which is the best method to use and why?  Or are they essentially the same?  I've searched high and low for the answer but have had no success.  Hopefully someone can explain this to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are *not* the same.  Using the `::` notation calls the method statically, which means that the method cannot access any class instance variables (like `$this->projectname`).  If the method does not make use of instance variables, then it is likely it should have been defined as a static method to begin with.

```
class projects {
  public static getSingleProject($projectid) {
    // function body
  }
}
```

[PHP documentation on `static` methods...](http://us.php.net/manual/language.oop5.static.php)

Comment: Ahh I see.  In terms of the difference between the two, does a static method carry less overhead if called in this manner?  Assuming it does not need any instance variables?

Comment: @gordyr Well technically, without an instance created, you would save a tiny bit of memory. But that's not really a reason to call statically.

Answer (score 2):

I would certainly recommend for you to stick to the first way. Static functions and variables introduce a form of global state.

You might benefit from materials here :

- http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/0103_static_considered_harmful.html
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F72VULWFvc

Answer (score 1):

Calling `projects::getSingleProject($projectid)` even if it's not declared `static` will still be valid in php. You will get an error if the method uses `$this` but in your case it looks like this is what's going on. It's probably not declared static and therefore you should not use it statically.